# In Flutter: Error when building a appBundle->* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, build, build.gradle

I am trying to build the appBundle to publish my app on google play.

I have this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              5,7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I create a key:
[image]

file key.properties:

```
storePassword=myPassWord
keyPassword=myPassWord
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=./keys.jks
```

Put this before the android

```
 def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
```

```
and this inside the android:
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

I follow the https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android,
not sure why I did wrong...

I try on google, with no luck. Recreate the key, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the file to put direct the data:

```
   keyAlias "upload"
   keyPassword "myPassWord"
   storeFile file(<path to file>)
   storePassword "myPassWord"
```

It worked. Not the best solution I guess.